# How to pass email address and password for creating emails in GMail?

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, gmail, cdo.message

I need my Access Database to create emails that are sent at the press of a button.

This works for Outlook, and I adapted the code for Gmail.

I don't want to hardcode the email username and password. I want to pick it up from a combobox on the main form.

I get the error
[image]

```vb
Private Sub Email_Allocation_List_Click()

    Dim newMail As CDO.Message
    Dim mailConfiguration As CDO.Configuration
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim msConfigURL As String
    
    On Error GoTo errHandle
    
    Set newMail = New CDO.Message
    Set mailConfiguration = New CDO.Configuration
    
    mailConfiguration.Load -1
    
    Set fields = mailConfiguration.fields
    
    With newMail
        .Subject = "subject"
        .From = [Forms]![Main form]![EmailAddress].Column(1)
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = "email address"
        .BCC = ""
        .TextBody = "Hello, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Please find attached todays list of lines to be allocated." & _
           vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Carly"
        .AddAttachment "file location"
    End With
    
    msConfigURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"
    
    With fields
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusing") = 2
        
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusername") = [Forms]![Main form]![EmailAddress].Column(1)
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendpassword") = [Forms]![Main form]![EmailAddress].Column(2)
        
        .Update
    
    End With
    
    newMail.Configuration = mailConfiguration
    newMail.Send
    
    MsgBox "E-Mail has been sent", vbInformation
    
    exit_line:
    '// Release object memory
    Set newMail = Nothing
    Set mailConfiguration = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
    errHandle:
    
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbInformation
    
    GoTo exit_line
    
End Sub
```

I checked the comboboxes work with a text box.

Comment: Obviously, there should not be a difference between hardcoding a value and supplying the same value from a form (or anywhere else). It's likely you're accidentally supplying the wrong value, or the wrong type (`CStr` can help you there). Start by printing out the value of `[Forms]![Main form]![EmailAddress].Column(1)` and `[Forms]![Main form]![EmailAddress].Column(2)`

Comment: @Erik A

I did that using the below and it was working fine for a text box (i've also tried to write it in this format rather than `[Forms]![Main form]![EmailAddress].Column(2)`



`Private Sub EmailAddress_Click()
Me.Password = Me.EmailAddress.Column(2)
end sub`

Comment: Code seems correct, so @ErikA 's comment seems spot on - your comboxes don't deliver what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around, you are correct, the code is fine - and it was reading the contents of the combo box correctly - however GMail didn't accept the log in information if there was a capital letter on the email address!!! Now working beautifully.